# Is GA Measurement protocol getting updated

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

According to here,

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en

GAU must be updated to GA4 properties. I'm using measurement protocol to send data to both GA4 and GAU properties. So in order to send measurement protocol to GA4 property should I update my existing measurement protocol apps?

I can send data to GA4 property using `v=2`, `tid=G-xxxxxxx` parameters at the endpoint `/g/collect`. Will any of this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Measurement Protocol (Universal Analytics)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en)
 is not being updated it will probably be discontinued when UA stops recording hits.

The [Measurement Protocol (Google Analytics 4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4) is still being developed.  It does not open for all events.

```
const measurementId = `<measurement_id_value>`;
const apiSecret = `<secret_value>`;

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurementId}&api_secret=${apiSecret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYYYY",
    "events": [{
      "name": "refund",
      "params": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "value": "9.99",
        "transaction_id": "ABC-123"
      }
    }]
  })
});
```